# How can I conditionally disable api routes in warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I am new to Rust and Warp and I am trying to make routes available conditionally. For example, I have a route `/leaves`, and based upon the `flag` I need to process this request or send an error response.

```
let enable_api = true // some config part

let leaves_filter = warp::path("leaves")
    .and(store_filter)
    .and(warp::path::param())
    .and(warp::path::param())
    .and_then(handler::handle_leaves)
    .boxed();

let routes = (info_filter).or(leaves_filter).boxed();
```

I tried to pass the `flag` to `handler::handle_leaves` and added a validation check to return a conditional response. But I want to know if we can filter the request before calling the handler.

What should be the good way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking tips from [Issue #21: How to execute a filter conditionally?](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/121) You will need to add a filter that can reject immediately if the flag is missing. So something like this:

```
let enable_api = true;

let leaves_filter = warp::path("leaves")
    .and_then(move || if enable_api { Ok(()) } else { Err(warp::reject::not_found()} })
    .and(store_filter)
    .and(warp::path::param())
    .and(warp::path::param())
    .and_then(|_, store, param1, param2| handler::handle_leaves(store, param1, param2));

let routes = info_filter.or(leaves_filter);
```